# Forcing application to create files with 0755 permission

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I'm running a game server (ut2004) on Centos 6. It creates demos, logs and other stuff which I need to process later with other applications. But the problem is - all these files have 0600 permission by default, while I need it to be 0755.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `umask` for this:

```
$ umask 100
$ touch d
$ ls -l d
-rw-rw-rw-  1 hashier  staff  0 Aug  9 16:20 d
$ umask 022
$ touch f
$ ls -l f
-rw-r--r--  1 hashier  staff  0 Aug  9 16:20 f
```

So what you want is set

umask 022

It is reset in every new login shell, so you might want to set it in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whatever you use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I checked the current umask for my user and it has already been 022. Even changing it to 000 in bashrc gave no effect too - files I create have the right permissions, but the game server (which I restarted ofc) still creates files with 0600 permissions. Seems like it's process doesn't inherit umask from me (root). Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/fstab`. It's just a guess but maybe the umask gets set there and maybe this takes precedence. If you run `mount` you can see the options with which the partition is mounted.

Comment: And wait... you and root are two different users? First: don't run the game server as root. Second: don't use root as your default user! NEVER! Third: umask set as a user and not in `/etc/fstab` is something per user. You can try to set it in the startup script for the game server but once again do NOT run the game server as root.

Answer (score 0):

Or you might want to try another way

```
$touch file
$chmod 755 file
```

Are you in control of the process that creates the files? Then add the second line below. :)